# Power BI angular Intregration Content not show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have tried to integrate PowerBi into my angular 1 app. I have used

```
<powerbi-report embed-url="selected.url" access-token="accessToken" id="selected.id"></powerbi-report>
```

to integrate power bi report.

I have made an api calls to get access token and embed Url and passed those to above element.

I am getting following output :

```
This content isn't available.
Learn more about Power BI.
```

I don't know why i am getting this. I couldn't find proper documentation in microsoft powerbi community. Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: did you found the solution? if you have the solution can you please post the entire steps to integrate PowerBI in angular, it would be helpful to us?

Answer (score 0):

The scenario `Access token` might be not valid for that report.

Just check network-tab in browser, find cluster api call should throw error 403 (forbidden). If yes, then your access token is the problem.